# Диаоговое окно выбора источника фотографии android

Tags: android

Как сделать диалоговое выбора источника фотографии? Нужно что то типа такого, только с 2 пунктами "Выбрать из галереи" и "Сфотографировать"
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

Этот код откроет диалог со списком приложений, которые поддерживают выбор изображения.

Где **SELECT_PHOTO** - любая константа типа **int**

кроме того вам нужно переопределить метод **onActivityResult** следующим образом

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case SELECT_PHOTO:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Этот метод вызовется, как только вы выберете картинку в выбранном в диалоге приложении. Выбранная картинка окажется в **Bitmap yourSelectedImage**

Comment: Таким способом в списке есть тольео Галлерея, нету пункта сделать фото. Как добавить пункт сделать фото?